# Is there a way to initialize members of a function to a none value to class member without default constructors?

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor, variant

I have some classes, having some members:

```
#include <variant>   

class A {
   public:
   A() {};

   private:
   B b;

   std::variant<B, C> var;
};

class B {
   public:
   B(C c) : c(c) {};

   private:
   C c;
};

class C {
   public:
   C(int val) val(val) {};

   private:
   int val;
};
```

Now, this does of course not compile because of two reasons: neither the class `B` nor `variant` has a default constructor. But I do not have any values for `B` or var yet, they will be initialized in the methods of `A`.

I have thought of the following:

- Defining a default constructor for `B`. But this way I will have an
  unnecessary constructor and I will have to do the same for `C` as well.
  As I might have multiple subclasses, this will lead to a cascade of
  unnecessary constructors quickly. Also, I cannot to this for not
  self-defined classes such as `std::variant`.
- Initializing the variables with dummy-values. While in practice this might work since I will overwrite the values quickly anyway, this is not very clean and can lead to some ugly bugs.
- Using Pointers. This is probably the most realistic one and the one I find most plausible, but I really wanted to avoid pointers here for some reason. Also, when I tried it with pointers, for some reason the members of B changed weirdly after returning the member. In addition, when trying to do this with variant (like `var = &C(0);`), I get told

> value of type "C *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type variant

Coming from Java, is there any way to just (without using pointers) initializing the values to something like `null`? I am aware that `null` does not exist is C++, but I am looking for something with the same effect / some workaround to the missing default constructors. Or is this a design-flaw in my classes and should be resolved different entirely?

Comment: Constructor is supposed to establish the class invariant. If you don't have all the data to construct `A`, then don't construct it. If you need an immediate object, with e.g. `std::optional<B>` and `std::optional<C>`, that's fine, but don't construct unless the invariant is established.

Comment: In C++, members are part of your class, just like your torso is part of your body. They can't "not be there". If you don't have a torso, then you don't have a body. If you don't have a `B` then you don't have an `A`.  You either need `std::optional`, or a pointer, because both of those are objects that themselves can hold a 'empty' value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`std::monostate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/monostate) in your variant until you've selected what type to store in it.

`std::monostate`:

> Unit type intended for use as a well-behaved empty alternative in `std::variant`. In particular, a variant of non-default-constructible types may list `std::monostate` as its first alternative: this makes the variant itself default-constructible.

Outline:

```cpp
class A {
public:
    A() = default;
    
    A(const B& b) : var(b) {}
    
    A(const C& c) : var(c) {}

    A& operator=(const B& b) {
        var = b;
        return *this;
    }

    A& operator=(const C& c) {
        var = c;
        return *this;
    }

private:
    std::variant<std::monostate, B, C> var;
};
```

---

A more generic version if you'd like to add more types to `A` without having to explicitly add constructors and assignment operators for them all:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <variant>

template<class... Ts>
class A_impl {
public:
    A_impl() = default;
    
    template<class T>
    requires std::disjunction_v<std::is_same<std::remove_cvref_t<T>, Ts>...>
    A_impl(T&& val) : var(std::forward<T>(val)) {}

    template<class T>
    requires std::disjunction_v<std::is_same<std::remove_cvref_t<T>, Ts>...>
    A_impl& operator=(T&& val) {
        var = std::forward<T>(val);
        return *this;
    }

private:
    std::variant<std::monostate, Ts...> var;
};

using A = A_impl<B, C>;
```

Comment: Nice to see some c++20 features being put to good use once in a while. Didn't know about `disjunction`. Edit : Never mind, it's c++17. I'm surprised I've never seen this before!

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux `disjunction` is actually a C++17 feature but I think it comes in handy even in C++20 constraints like above.

Comment: Aside, `std::monostate` can also be used like a **unit** type as found in some other languages.  (Those other languages may use the term *monad*, which to C++ programmers is a lot like saying "it" to the Knights Who Say Ni!  To demystify *monad*: a monad is a function that takes one parameter and returns one result.  Nothing to be scared about. Monad-centric languages **only** allow monad functions.  That may be a bit scary.)